# htaccess Redirect 301 friendly link with non friendly tail

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I have a problem with 301 redirect in .htaccess file.
Yes it should be done in htaccess.

I have friendly link with non friendly tail with utf-8 characters:

```
https://example.com/plotno-16x24?tag=Fotobraz na płótnie
```

Im tryin to redirect it to 
https://example.com/404 with code:

```
RewriteRule ^plotno-16-24?tag=([^?]*)$ /404 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

But it works only before question mark, after this sign "?" it always fail.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

`?` or part of QUERY_STRING is not matched in `RewriteRule`. You may use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /plotno-16-24\?tag=. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /404? [R=30,L,NE]
```

Also note use of `?` after `/404` that strips off any pre-existing query string.